# Fast Folding Algorithm Implementation

Tags: algorithm

I have some times series data and I would like to use an algorithm to detect periodic events in this time series.
I read that Fast Folding Algorithm is used to detect pulsars stars, but I didnt find any example code of how it is done. Where can I find it?